# Proper way to create a RadioField with a dynamic default value?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

Here's the code I've got, and this works. `MyForm` is a form class, which defines only a `RadioField`. The `RadioField`has no default specified here, because we don't know what items it will contain yet. `my_form` takes a list of items and creates a `MyForm` with the items added to the `RadioField`, and (crucially) picks the first item in the list to be the default.

```
from wtforms.fields.core import RadioField
from wtforms.validators import Required
from flask_wtf.form import Form

class MyForm(Form):
    """
    User chooses an item.
    """
    itemid = RadioField(validators=[Required()])

def my_form(items):
    """
    Returns a MyForm object populated with appropriate items.
    """
    form = MyForm()
    form.itemid.choices = [(item.id, item.name)
        for item in sorted(items, key=lambda i: i.order)]
    if items and form.itemid.data == u'None':
        # None ensures we don't overwrite submitted data
        form.itemid.data = items[0].id
    return form
```

The check `and form.itemid.data == u'None'` just smells really bad. The reason for this is that without that check, we overwrite submitted data. I.e. when we use the form like this...

```
@APP.route('/page_one', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def page_one():
    form = my_form(dynamic_items())
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        itemid = form.itemid.data
        return redirect(url_for('page_two', itemid=itemid))
    else:
        return render_template('page_one.html', form=form)
```

... if we don't have that smelly check, we set the form data so as to set the default, but in the case that `form.validate_on_submit()` will pass because the user has submitted the form, by setting the default we've clobbered the actual data submitted by the user.

Of course, the obvious answer seems to be that `my_form` should just set the default, so the smelly check should just become:

```
if items:
    form.itemid.default = items[0].id
```

But that doesn't work, seemingly because form.itemid.data has no data, and that's what's actually used to construct the HTML.

So the question is: what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using `my_form()` for both form creation and form validation.  Do you need to call:

```
form = my_form(create_items())
```

or can you simply use:

```
form = MyForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    ...
```

Then `my_form()` is only for form creation.

Comment: The `MyForm` needs to be populated with items, both for display and for validation. I guess I could have `form = my_form_for_submission(items)` that doesn't set the default, then `if form.validate_on_submit()`, then `form = my_form_for_display(items)` to create a new instance that has the default set, to display to the user. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes.  Keeping the functionality separate will make it easier in the long run.  Share code where you can (DRY) and don't complicate functions with conditionals.

Comment: Okay, I'm happy to accept that as the answer. But can you point to any references that suggest that the same Form instance should not generally be used both for checking for validation/submission as well as for display? For a counterexample, [see The Flask Mega-Tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms). Perhaps this is discredited or outdated?

Comment: Flask and Django use the single request method, while Webapp2 (Google's App Engine) uses the split get() and post() methods: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/gettingstarted/handlingforms.html

You can choose the style that works best for you.  I am strongly in favor of very simple methods: build a form or validate a form, not both.  It will make it easier for you to extend them later on (with AJAX, for example).  Oh, and fewer "smelly" checks, too!

Comment: But this _is_ flask. What is the single request method solution to this problem?

Comment: It's your choice, really.  You can "@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])" for a single method, or you can split them up.  My preference is to split them up.